# Coding color scheme for programming in Windows, not just Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, themes

Like many SO people, I'm in front of a computer almost all day. I like having a dark theme for Visual Studio (easier on the eyes), but since the rest of Windows and apps (explorer, dialogs, Outlook), have the full white background, it's even harder to switch between nice dark VS and sunshine bright Windows.

I tried a UXTheme.dll patch but couldn't find any dark themes that worked across Visual Studio and Windows apps in general. Any suggestions?

Edit: To be clear, I'd like no or almost no white. No scrollbars, menus, etc.

Comment: ooh i hate you people. Ironic Sans says it best: http://www.ironicsans.com/owmyeyes/

Comment: @nickf: The page you linked to has white text on a black background.  This is extremely hard on your eyes.  I, like the original question author, like dark themes that are well contrasted, not pure white on black.  Not only are dark themes better for your eyes, but they can reduce power consumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find a Windows theme that can accomplish your task.  Many software applications do not adhere to colors specified in Windows preferences and are not at all customizable--Notepad, for example, is black text on a white background, end of story.

For themes in general, Microsoft has released two official XP themes within the last year that may be worth looking at:

- [Zune](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=75078)
- [Embedded](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?aywudxvynnq)

If you are planning on using a [modified uxtheme.dll](http://lifehacker.com/5056544/how-to-use-custom-windows-visual-styles) file, you can check out [Luna Element Black](http://gelosea.deviantart.com/art/Luna-Element-v5-1-Black-57571128), which is one I have used for well over a year now.

If you are this passionate about not having white areas visible in some of the programs you use, perhaps you need to find new applications that provide similar features but also offer customization in terms of fonts and colors--for example, using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) instead of Notepad, which gives you an almost exhaustive amount of customization possibilities.

Comment: With a modified uxtheme, this one works very well I found: http://dynacord.deviantart.com/art/Fleur-de-lys-91935309
Still, modifying the colors, VS doesn't totally skin (Solution Explorer ends up white, with white text). Sigh.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 is reportedly going to be written in WPF so hopefully they'll make it look more like Expression Studio--which has an excellent dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

May be not exactly what you are looking for, but [this is a dark color scheme](http://www.mohundro.com/blog/CommentView,guid,0a1943d0-c755-41bc-bc1a-246d0f38b6a1.aspx) for visual Studio (2005 or 2008) you may use in complement of UXTheme.

Off course, they are other dar color schemes for Visual studio, like [this one](http://www.agileprogrammer.com/dotnetguy/archive/2006/09/07/19030.aspx) (Jeff [has one also](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000682.html)).

But I am not sure there is *one* tool that applies to all windows, including Visual Studio.